# Retrieve tag values in an html document

Tags: c#, html, xml, html-table, linq-to-xml

If I have an HTML document, how is the best way to retrieve all tag values within a table?

Here is an example:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <table border="1">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </body>
</html>
```

How can I retrieve all the th values in the thead? I am also wanting to retrieve all the values in the tbody table rows.

I have tried to write some XML document code but with no luck. Can I please have some code to help me?

**UPDATE**

Here is my current code I am working on:

```
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(textBoxBugTrackFilename.Text))
{
    String line = sr.ReadToEnd();
    var document = XDocument.Parse(line);

    var headings = document.Element("thead").Elements().Select(x => x.Value);
    foreach (var h in headings)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(h.ToString());
    }
}
```

I am getting this error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

At line:

```
var headings = document.Element("thead").Elements().Select(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: This question does not show much effort on your part.  Consider showing some code that attempts to solve the problem you describe.

Comment: how do you attempt to get the values?in backend/frontend?

Comment: Can you have a look at my update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement `.Element("thead")` should be

```
.Descendants("thead").First()
```

The problem with you getting a null exception is because the element `thead` is not a first level child of the `html` tag.  It is a descendant.

Better because even with `.Descendants("thead").First()` is that there is a sub-element `tr` below that, then the `th` elements.

Instead change your code like below:

```
var headings = document.Descendants("th")
                       .Select(th => th.Value);
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try getElementsByTagName()?

Do you want to solve this using only Javascript? or you can use jQuery?

Using jQuery you can use $('table').find()